# How would I be able to make a binary search tree with the numbers from a dynamic array?

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, dynamic-arrays

I was trying to make a binary tree with int values from a dynamic array and traverse through it with in-sort, pre-sort and post-sort. The dynamic array was sorted so I am not sure why the tree did not take the values from the array?

I included the code I used:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct myTree { 
    int value; 
    struct myTree *right, *left; 
}; 

typedef struct myTree _tree; 

//insert the node into the tree
void insertNode(_tree *(*tree), _tree *item) { 
  if (!(*tree)) { 
     *tree = item;
     return; 
  } 
  if (item->value < (*tree)->value){
      insertNode(&(*tree)->left, item);
  }       
  else if(item->value > (*tree)->value){
      insertNode(&(*tree)->right, item); 
  }
} 

//pre-order
void PreOrder(_tree *tree) { 
  printf("%d\n",tree->value); 
  if (tree->left != NULL) PreOrder(tree->left); 
  if (tree->right != NULL) PreOrder(tree->right); 
} 

//parse the tree
void ParseTree(int array[], int start, int arrSize, int sorted[]) {
int middle;
static int count = 0; //acts like global variable
  if (start > arrSize) return;
  middle = (start + arrSize) / 2;
  sorted[count] = array[middle];
  count++;
  ParseTree(array, start, middle-1, sorted);
  ParseTree(array, middle+1, arrSize, sorted);
}

//selection sort of array
void InsertionSort(int arrName[], int arrSize){
    int temp;
    for(int step = 1; step < arrSize; step++){
        int key = arrName[step];
        int j = step-1;

        while(key < arrName[j] && j >= 0){
            arrName[j+1] = arrName[j];
            --j;
        }
        arrName[j+1] = key;
    }

}
   

int main(void){
    FILE *fO; 
    int number, i;
    int count = 0;
    _tree *current, *root;
    //pointer for dynamic array
    int *dynamicArray, *sortedArray;
    fO = fopen("intfile.txt", "r");


    while(1){
        fscanf(fO, "%d", &number);
        printf("%d\n", number);
        count++;
        //terminate loop
        if(feof(fO)){
            break;
        }   
    }
    FILE *neuF;
    neuF = fopen("intfile.txt", "r");
    int *Val;

    printf("count: %i\n", count);
    //create dynamic array
    dynamicArray = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));

    //insert into dynamic array
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
        fscanf(neuF, "%d", &dynamicArray[i]);
        
    }
    //add ints into dynamic array
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
        printf("in: %d\n", dynamicArray[i]);
    }
    if(dynamicArray == NULL){
        printf("not allocated.\n");
    }

    //sort the dynamic array
    InsertionSort(dynamicArray, count);

    sortedArray = (int*)calloc(count, sizeof(int));

    ParseTree(dynamicArray, 0, count, sortedArray);
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
        printf("%d %d\n", dynamicArray[i], sortedArray[i]);
    }
    //fclose(fO);
    free(dynamicArray);

    //make the tree
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
        current = (_tree*)malloc(sizeof(_tree));
        current->left = current->right = NULL;
        current->value = sortedArray[i];
        insertNode(&root, current);   
    }
    

    //print out the tree
    printf("Show Pre-Order:\n");
    InOrder(root);
    

}
```

The integer file was just a file with just one integer for each line. I think the problem is with how the binary tree was made because the dynamic allocation seemed to work. I was hoping that it would just print out the pre,in,and post order traversals but it is not printing them. It is showing that the sorting functions worked.
Do you have suggestions for what I could do to fix the tree?

---

input file: 3, 2, 5, 6, 5, 8, 9, 7 (one on each line)

expected output:
(it is just the standard pre-order traversal for a BinarySearchTree)
Show Pre-order: 5, 3, 2, 4, 8, 6, 7, 9 (one on each line)

my output:
count:9
*nothing is printed where pre-order should be displayed*

the dynamic array, insertionSort and parse all work, so I am wondering if there is a small issue I have missed.

Comment: Please reduce the code to a [mre]. For example, if none of the `Order` functions work then just ask about one of them. Also, please give the exact input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: `_tree *root;` That is an uninitailised variable and can contain any indeterminate value. But the `insertNode` function expects it to be NULL on the first call. So need to init it:  `_tree *root = NULL;`.

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong:

```
dynamicArray = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

This allocates memory for exactly one `int`. You want this:

```
dynamicArray = malloc(sizeof(int) * count);
```

or (to be consistent with other parts of your code):

```
dynamicArray = calloc(count, sizeof(int));
```

BTW the `(int*)` cast is not needed.

Comment: thank you @jabberwocky, that actually helped.  I think the issue now is just the loading of the binary tree or the pre-order traversal printing.